# How to properly use random projection to significantly reduce the dimensions of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

In my application, I have a vectors of arbitrary length, but that normally fall in the range of between 0 and 500 elements. Each value in the vector is between `-1` and `1`. I am computing the similarity of two arbitrary vectors with the following SQL:

`1 - SUM(ABS(v1.value - v2.value)) / COUNT(*)`

(where `v1.value` and `v2.value` refer to values of the same matching item)

However, the dimensions are too large for these on-the-fly similarity calculations, so I would like to perform dimension reduction to improve performance.

I found out about random projection, and I am trying to apply it, but I'm not having much luck it seems, and was wondering if anyone could spot the flaw in my logic.

First, I expensively computed the similarity between X and Y (two vectors, each with 100 dimensions). This was so that I could know what value I should be shooting for after performing dimension reduction.

I first generated 8 vectors of the maximum possible length (100), all filled with random values between -1 and 1. Let's call them V1 to V8.

I then computed the similarity of X against V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, and V8, and saved that vector of respective results as X1. I also computed the similarity of Y against V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, and V8 and saved that vector of respective results as Y1.

I then computed the similarity of X1 against Y1 with the above SQL (the same method used to compute the similarity between X and Y), but got a much different result than when I computed the similarity of X against Y. This is unfortunate because I think random projection is quoted as being surprisingly accurate, so I was hoping the similarity between X and Y would be very close to the similarity between X1 and Y1.

To clarify, X and Y are the original vectors, and X1 and Y1 are the resultant "reduced dimension" vectors.

So my questions are:

1) Did I do this properly? I'm not sure if I fully understand random projection yet so maybe I messed up a step

2) How do you determine how many random vectors to compute against? Most of my vectors are going to have between 100 and 300 dimensions. How many dimensions should my reduced vectors have and still be reasonably accurate?

3) Is this possibly not working because I am using the Manhattan Distance instead of the Euclidean Distance? I initially chose the former because the computation is much simpler and I needed it to be fast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot (indeed, hardly anything) about random projection, but I'm guessing that the projections are supposed to be *orthogonal* projections. That would require that your $V$ vectors be unit-length and mutually perpendicular (with respect to the inner product you're using).

A deeper problem is that you've got vectors in various-dimensional spaces, and you're putting them all into one large-dimensional space (by filling with zeroes?) and computing inner products --- that seems like a very peculiar choice. Before advising further on how to make random projection work, I'd like to know the nature of the data we're working with. For instance, it sounds as if your resulting dataset might have a real "preference" for certain axis-aligned subspaces (those consisting of vectors with lots of zeroes at the ends). It'd be useful to know whether that has any interactions with the assumptions of the theorems about random projection.

Finally, using the Manhattan metric might have serious consequences as well.

Short summary: read the theorems on random projections and look at their hypotheses closely to see whether they apply to your situation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! So to answer some of your questions to help explain the situation better: the data that I'm working with is that users can rate something anywhere between -1.0 and 1.0 in my interface. The specific bounds aren't too important. If it would make it work then I could sacrifice that and make it work between 0 and 10 (integers instead). Although I would really like for there to remain a decent amount of .. is entropy the word? So like, I would prefer to preserve the ability to give a very nuanced rating (so at least be able to give >10 different options)

Comment: As for the filling with zeroes comment, if I understand you properly: I am only computing similarity between matched values. So if user1 rated only items 1, 3, 4, and 7, and user2 only rated items 3, 7, and 9, then their X and Y vectors before computing similarity would consist only of items 3 and 7 (since they only share those). So if user1 rated item 3 as a -0.5 and item 7 as 1.0, and user2 rate item 3 as -0.25 and item 7 as 0.75, then vectors X and Y prior to computing similarity would be [ -0.5, 1.0 ] and [ -0.25, 0.75 ] respectively. Does that make sense?

Comment: @RyanPeschel Linear algebraic data analysis methods would really prefer to have all data in the same space. Would it be highly detrimental to your analysis to replace null values with some "neutral" value like 0 on a scale from -1 to 1?

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure if that would work.. Like for example, if there were 300 items to rate, and two users only rated 2 of them, wouldn't all the 298 zeroes drag down the similarity score to almost nothing?

Comment: @RyanPeschel That said the main thing that seems wrong in what you said in the OP is that you want to project X and Y into the span of V1 to V8, which cannot be done by projecting onto each separately and summing the projections unless the V's are orthogonal. Computing this projection properly in the Euclidean metric is a standard problem (a keyword you can look up is the normal equations). In the Manhattan metric it is a lot more complicated to compute the analogue of projections (i.e. the closest point in some subspace to a point not in the subspace).

Comment: @Ian: Sorry I am trying to keep up with your explanation but math is not my strong suit whatsoever. I think what you're saying is that Manhattan distance won't work and I would have to use Euclidian distance instead to have this work? If that is the case then I can definitely change the algorithm. I'm fine with whatever lets this work well enough to be honest.

Comment: @RyanPeschel How exactly is similarity defined? Is it basically the covariance, i.e. the dot product of the vectors divided by the product of their norms? If so then zero padding can drag down the result yes. But if you aren't in the same space then you can't really expect linear algebra methods to help.

Comment: @Ian I put the algorithm that I'm using at the beginning of the original post (the SQL). Basically I'm looking for a way to roughly calculate the similarity (that I will then display as a percentage on the frontend). So are you saying that what I'm attempting is not possible? That I can't reduce the dimensions accurately because all the zero padding will drag down the result?

Comment: @RyanPeschel So I'm saying two things: first that you will not be able to use the Manhattan metric and still efficiently compute projections, and second that to correctly compute projections in the Euclidean metric then you need to solve the normal equations, or else generate the vectors you're projecting onto to be orthogonal in the first place.

Comment: @RyanPeschel The conceptual problem I have with your idea is that as the results that were submitted by the pair of users being compared varies, you have to recompute the projection matrix every single time, which is going to take a comparable amount of time (perhaps more, actually) to just computing the similarity directly. It would perform better if the number of entries was always fixed, then you could do all your dimension reduction with the same projection matrix which you could then precompute.

Comment: You've got two vectors $X$ and $Y$, representing ratings users gave (or lack of ratings). These are approximations of the users' true views on *all* items --- let's call those $X'$ and $Y'$. You've defined a notion of "similarity" between $X$ and $Y$ vectors, but it's not actually a "distance" in any reasonable sense. Here's an example to show why: $X = (*, 1), Y = (1, 1), Z = (1, *), W = (1, -1)$. The similarities (0 means "perfect agreement") are $s(X, Y) = 0, s(Y, Z) = 0, S(Z, W) = 0, s(W, X) = 1$. So "s" is nothing like a distance function. Hence proj'n theorems are useless to you.

Comment: @Ian Okay, I'm trying to figure out a way out of this hole that I'm in then.. what if I ... padded everything out with zeroes .. and ... had the possible rating values be -100,000, -90,000, -80,000, -70,000, -60,000, -50,000, -40,000, -30,000, -20,000, -10,000, 10,000, 20,000, 30,000, 40,000, 50,000, 60,000, 70,000, 80,000, 90,000 and 100,000? Then even though the zero values exist they don't really account for much? They don't drag things down? Not sure..

Comment: @RyanPeschel No, that won't even do anything at all because you have to renormalize the sum to get the similarity between -1 and 1.

Comment: Is there anything I can do then? Or is the problem just completely intractable? I'm open to any ideas.

Comment: Well...about a million people have looked at this question before, using some name like "collaborative recommendation systems"; they're the basis for the list of books amazon recommends right after you've bought Goodnight, Moon, and so on. I'd start by looking at that literature.

Comment: I don't think I'm intelligent enough in this sphere to be able to evaluate the literature. That's partly why I explained my entire problem domain and asked for which algorithm would work. If this has been done so often then I'd imagine there must be a path forward? Given what you know, are you aware of any specific solutions that would work in my specific use-case? Or maybe I should ask a separate question because this one is about random projection.

Comment: No...as I said in my answer I barely knwo about random projection. Collaborative Recommendation is another area i've heard a bit about, but really am not an expert in.